# What does "can see for doing something" mean?

Tags: meaning

It's for the 16 episode of the 9th season of *Friends*. Here it is:

> Phoebe: Hi
>
> Ross: Hey!
>
> Phoebe: Listen, I wanted to ask you something about marriage.
>
> Ross: Oh great now you're seeking me out to make jokes? I mean **I** **can
> see for all hanging out** but to come to my home!
>
> Phoebe: No...I really wanted to know how you feel about it.

Comment: It doesn't quite make sense. Is a video link available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a transcription error. His line is actually:

> Oh, great, now you’re *seeking me out* to make jokes? I mean, I can see if we're all hanging out, but to come to my home...

(Emphasis mine.) He's saying it's okay to joke around casually, *when they're all hanging out* (socializing as a group), but pointing out that she is now coming to his home.